# Is asking for the "proper" use of the word "chemical" a case of linguistic prescriptivism?

Tags: word-usage, science

Another [Skeptics.SE user and I are discussing the meaning of the word "prescriptivism"](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3014/23). (Yes, we are aware of the recursion involved.)

In particular, I have cited a couple of examples of scientists objecting the usage of the word "chemical" by the general public and in marketing, to refer to "artificial additives" rather than the standard scientific definition.

- [$2.3 million bounty offered for “100% chemical-free material”](http://web.cosmosmagazine.com/news/23-million-bounty-offered-100-chemical-free-material/)
- [Hell to the no! Chemical-free chemistry kit](http://www.thejayfk.com/?p=621)

I argue that these are two cases of linguistic prescriptivism.
He disagrees:

> What linguists term prescriptive usage are those elements of grammar/pronunciation that are perceived to be "proper" and are typically associated to the speech of the speakers of the language who have the most power (in the west, educated middle class/upper middle class speakers). Often times they are in fact out of sync with what people actually say (even in the prestige group). So the scientifically driven ones are really not part of what linguists characterize as prescriptive language. I would say that's scientific pedantry...

I'm no expert, and I am happy to be corrected, but this doesn't go along with my understanding.

Should demands to only use the word "chemical" in the scientific sense be considered "linguistic prescriptivism", "scientific pedantry", both or neither?

Comment: The sense Google dictionary claims to be the most commonly used for the adjectival usage of _chemical_ is: 'relating to chemistry, or the interactions of substances as studied in chemistry.
"the chemical composition of the atmosphere"' This is very broad (I wouldn't say 'loose', as that implies wrongdoing already). If an authority seeks to impose a stricter definition on the population at large, that's certainly prescriptivism (semantic, not grammar or pronunciation) and even dictatorialness. If an authority seeks to restrict usage in a given domain, whether or not the evaluation ...

Comment: 'This is prescriptivist' applies will need an agreeing on the precise definition of 'prescriptivist' itself. One is arguing about terminology here. 'Agreeing terms' in a given domain is standard scientific procedure. What domains that standardisation of terms applies to is the key question. 'Science' is disingenuous; there are as many arguments among scientists as among linguists.

Comment: @Edwin: Your first couple of sentences take us on a wild goose chase. That is not the problematical usage of "chemical". The noun form indicating artificial additive is the controversial one.

Comment: @Edwin: I agree that I am looking for clarity on the meaning of "prescriptivist", and so I am asking here to hear from the experts. While scientists do argue, they don't argue much about the definition of "chemical" or "chemical substance"; they have reached a broad consensus; I am hoping the linguists have too for "prescriptivist".

Comment: What ***is*** the standard scientific definition of chemical? Do you have a dictionary that contains it? Is it the same as *"molecule"*? If so, why do scientists use two words for the same thing?

Comment: @Peter: We are getting off topic here, but chemical (as a noun) is short for chemical substance. Wikipedia draws a definition from the Compendium of Chemical Terminology: "In chemistry, a chemical substance is a form of matter that has constant chemical composition and characteristic properties. It cannot be separated into components by physical separation methods, i.e. without breaking chemical bonds. It can be solid, liquid, gas, or plasma." It is NOT the same as "molecule" (e.g. metals are chemicals, but not made of molecules).

Comment: @Oddthinking: so a chemical substance is a form of matter that has ***constant chemical composition***. If I interpret this properly, in the process of growing an organic apple, no chemical substances were ever created, since the biological processes involved never purified any chemicals. However, you can *extract* chemical substances from an apple by using chemical processing (just like you can *extract* metal from blood by using chemical processing).

Comment: Just to be clear here, the term 'scientific pedantry' was used tongue in cheek. (Smiley in the original.) Also, I am a working linguist, and although I don't speak for the entire field I'm fairly sure that my definition is fairly standard. And although there are some linguists here, EL&U is not primarily inhabited by linguists, I would say.

Comment: ... On the other hand, if you water the apple tree, you're applying a chemical.

Comment: @AlanMunn: You are a linguist? Oh! *looks embarrassed* I should have probably just taken your word for it.

Comment: @PeterShor: Uh, an apple is not a chemical. It is made of a mixture of chemicals. Saying an apple does not contain chemicals just because they were never purified is an unconventional usage of the term. We are definitely off-topic now.

Comment: @Oddthinking Hey, I'm no fan of argument by authority either, so there's no reason to take my word for it. However, it's not so obvious to me that EL&L (wise though it is) is the best place to ask a question that is fundamentally about practice in linguistics. (Not that Linguistics.sx would better; it's also sparsely populated with linguists as far as I can tell.)

Comment: There's a linguistics Stack Exchange? I am learning more and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) has:

> The main aims of linguistic prescription are to specify standard
>   language forms either generally ([but] what is Standard English?) or
>   for specific purposes ...

So trying to tie people down to one usage in total, or one usage in a given article or domain say, would both qualify as 'prescriptivism' according to this definition.

However, trying to totally quash alternative senses of a word as given in dictionaries such as AHDEL and Collins would be over-prescriptivist (and would be arrogant and doomed to failure).

But trying to clear up and restrict the actual sense intended for a word as used in an article or on food labels would be sensibly prescriptivist, clarifying, and probably most sensibly called 'definition of terms': 'In this article, 'function' is defined as ...'.

When you say

> In particular, I have cited a couple of examples of scientists
>   objecting the usage of the word "chemical" by the general public and
>   in marketing, to refer to "artificial additives" rather than the
>   standard scientific definition.

you would give a truer picture if you rephrased to

> In particular, I have cited a couple of examples of scientists
>   objecting to the use of the word "chemical" by the general public
>   and in marketing to refer to "artificial additives" rather than in accordance with other
>   equally acceptable definitions [see eg EA's comment] without clarification of terminology.

Answer (score -2):

It seems sensible to acknowledge from the start that it will never be possible to get individual members of the general public to abandon the sloppy/colloquial use of the term *chemical* against their will.

But what *can* be done is to restrict the way science-related terms are used in marketing and advertising – in other words, those arenas where the scientific illiteracy of the public (which is enormous in the USA, according to research from the Pew Research Center [see here](http://www.people-press.org/2013/04/22/publics-knowledge-of-science-and-technology/), [and here](http://www.pewforum.org/2013/12/30/publics-views-on-human-evolution/)) is most prone to being exploited by unscrupulous companies peddling worthless or dangerous products.

The best way to achieve this seems to me to define and regulate the science-related terminology permitted in marketing and advertising so that it conforms to scientific norms. Under such a regulatory scheme, the loose use of the noun *chemical(s)* would thus be banned, such that the word could not legally be used in promotional material except as part of a collocation having a defined scientific meaning, such as *chemical compound*, or possibly in a few narrowly-defined contexts. Advertisers should have to specify what classes of chemicals they are referring to, such as *synthetic colourings*, or the actual names of the chemicals they are mentioning.

The way pharmaceuticals, nicotine products and alcohol are advertised is already subject to fairly strict regulation in most countries. So the precedent already exists for placing limits on the use of particular terminology in advertising, and forcing advertisers to use scientific terms accurately in *all* advertising would merely extend the same principle more widely.

One might then hope that over time, the public's understanding of the term *chemical* (as well as other scientific terminology) will become more sophisticated and well-informed, especially as younger and (hopefully) better-educated generations reach maturity, thereby reducing the incentive for companies to use misleading science-related terminology in the first place.

To address the OP's explicit question, such restrictions would introduce neither *linguistic prescriptivism* nor *scientific pedantry,* but *scientific accuracy* (or something that is as close as one might hope to get to it in general advertising).